# Calculate minimum accuracy for a majority voting algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning

Suppose, you are working on a binary classification problem. And there are 3 models each with 70% accuracy. If you want to ensemble these models using majority voting, what is the minimum accuracy you can get?

Answer (score 0):

Majority voting guarantees you an accuracy of **at least 70%**. Ensemble model predictions are wrong if at least two base classifiers are wrong. So a maximum of 30% can be classified incorrectly.

- **Acc = 70%**: if two models came up with the same predictions.
- **Acc > 70%**: in any other case.

*As a side note: Not so sure about calling this boosting. It's kind of boosting in the sense that it turns a bunch of weak learners into a strong learner… However, majority voting or even OneRule classifier as meta learners are (maybe) less misleading.*

Comment: What's the easiest way to prove this?  Exactly 70% accuracy can be achieved in other situations, e.g. classifier A is correct on the first 70%, B on the last 70%, and C on a middle 70%.  (C always concurs correctly with one of A,B.)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum is actually **55%**.  Here was my first example achieving 60% accuracy, which helps inform the improvement in the next paragraph.  Each row is one of the models, and each column is 10% of the data; an `x` indicates the model being incorrect on that decile.

```
xxAxAAAAAA
xBxxBBBBBB
CxxxCCCCCC
```

That fourth column of all `x`s is wasteful, so we're going to have the three models all be correct on a subset of the data of proportion $t$, and with the remaining $1-t$ they will cycle the rest of their $0.7-t$ correct answers such that only one of them is correct on any point.  This means that $3\cdot(0.7-t)=1-t$, and so $t=0.55$.

This is, to me, clearly the worst possible, because we've "wasted" correct votes maximally.  But I don't have an elegant proof, and this should definitely already exist somewhere...